# error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use OpenAI's API to make an app in Next.js to generate mcq and open-ended questions. But on trying out the endpoint in Postman I am getting this error:

> error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:266:61)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Here is my code:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { quizCreationSchema } from "@/schemas/form/quiz"
import { ZodError } from "zod"
import { strict_output } from "@/lib/gpt"

// POST /api/questions
export const POST = async (req: Request, res: Response) =>{
  try {
    const body = await req.json()
    const {amount, topic, type} = quizCreationSchema.parse(body)
    let questions: any;
    if(type === 'open_ended') {
      questions = await strict_output(
        'You are a helpful AI that is able to generate a pair of questions and answers, the length of the answer should not exceed 15 words, store all the pairs of answers and questions in a JSON array',
        new Array(amount).fill(`You are to generate a random hard open-ended question about the ${topic}`),
        {
          question: "question",
          answer: "answer with max length of 15 words",
        }
      );
    } else if(type === 'mcq'){
      questions = await strict_output(
        'You are a helpful AI that is able to generate mcq questions and answers, the length of each answer should not exceed 15 words',
        new Array(amount).fill(`You are to generate a random mcq question about ${topic}`),
      {
        question: "question",
        answer: "answer with max length of 15 words",
        option1: "1st option with max length of 15 words",
        option2: "2nd option with max length of 15 words",
        option3: "3rd option with max length of 15 words",
      }
      )
    }
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
      questions,
  },
  {
    status: 200
  });
  } catch (error) {
      if(error instanceof ZodError) {
        return NextResponse.json({
          error: error.issues,
        }, 
        {
          status: 400
        })
      }
  }
}
```

I am expecting a JSON of the questions but I am getting 500 internal server error in Postman and the above mentioned error in console.

Comment: Hi Aritra, have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

This error often happens when an API route does not return a response. It may be because you are getting an error in your `try-cach` that's not an instance of `ZodError`. Try changing it to:

```typescript
// ...

export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { amount, topic, type } = quizCreationSchema.parse(body);
    let questions: any = [];
    if (type === "open_ended") {
      questions = await strict_output(
        "You are a helpful AI that is able to generate a pair of questions and answers, the length of the answer should not exceed 15 words, store all the pairs of answers and questions in a JSON array",
        new Array(amount).fill(
          `You are to generate a random hard open-ended question about the ${topic}`
        ),
        {
          question: "question",
          answer: "answer with max length of 15 words",
        }
      );
    } else if (type === "mcq") {
      questions = await strict_output(
        "You are a helpful AI that is able to generate mcq questions and answers, the length of each answer should not exceed 15 words",
        new Array(amount).fill(`You are to generate a random mcq question about ${topic}`),
        {
          question: "question",
          answer: "answer with max length of 15 words",
          option1: "1st option with max length of 15 words",
          option2: "2nd option with max length of 15 words",
          option3: "3rd option with max length of 15 words",
        }
      );
    }
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        questions,
      },
      {
        status: 200,
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          error: error.issues,
        },
        {
          status: 400,
        }
      );
    }
    // For logs purpose
    console.log(error);
    // You should return a response in all cases
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: "Unexpected error occured",
      },
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );
  }
};
```